# C# loop to specific rows in Excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel

Can anyone help me I want my C# code to start loop and print at row number 5 in my Excel file.

Here is my current code:

```
            DataColumnCollection dataColumnCollection = dataTable.Columns;

            for (int i = 1; i <= dataTable.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 1)
                        excelApplication.Cells[i, j] = dataColumnCollection[j - 1].ToString();
                    else
                        excelApplication.Cells[i, j] = dataTable.Rows[i - 2][j - 1].ToString();
                }
```

Here is my sample data:
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSeFJ.jpg)

And here is what I want the file to look like:
[sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/996Mi.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all arrays and lists the like start at `0` in most cases.

In your case if you want to start at row 5, simply increment the start with 5.

```
            const int start = 5;
            int end = datadataTable.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0 + start; i < end; i++) // loop from 5..end
            {

                for (int j = 1; j <= dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 1)
                        excelApplication.Cells[i, j] = dataColumnCollection[j - 1].ToString();
                    else
                        excelApplication.Cells[i, j] = dataTable.Rows[i - 2][j - 1].ToString();
                }
```

Comment: @aidel go ahead and mark this answer for completion if this answers your question, else please provide more details on what you need.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. It cuts straight to row 5 of my data, not data from the start. I wish to make the data start looping at row 5 in my Excel file. Do you know where went wrong?

Comment: @AidelIbrahim what do you mean with 'start looping' what do you mean by that? post some example data and output in the answer if you could.